# Qprocess issue argument is empty but passed current directory

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I'm running QProcess from my GUI application (for example "gedit"), but when agruments is empty then argument passed the current directory.

```
QString program = "gedit";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << text(); // it's QLIneEdit function
m_editTextProcess->start(program, arguments); // m_editTextProcess is a QProcess pointer
```

.................................

when arguments is empty then argument passed current directory.

Comment: Please include in your question what exactly you are doing (provide some code) and what exactly the error (message) is.

Comment: Well, my answer was not fitting (it's friday!). However it seems to me  that the problem is related to the behaviour of gedit with an empty parameter list, more than a wrong dir parameter.